# Which are Java's system classes?

Tags: java, assertions

When reading some documentation about assertions, I found:

```
java -ea -dsa
```

> "Enables assertions in general, but
>   disables assertions in system
>   classes."

Which are the system classes?

Comment: My guess is  those in "java.lang.*"

Comment: By the way that exact configuration is unnecessary. -ea without any parameters implies -dsa. However if you did -ea and specified a package, then you need to think about -dsa.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the [assertions documentation](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/guide/lang/assert.html#enable-disable), system classes are classes "which do not have an explicit class loader", i.e. the classes loaded by the bootstrap classloader. AFAIK that means the contents of `rt.jar`, the entire standard API.

Comment: The endorsed directory as well. Not sure about extension directories (which have a definitely non-null class loader).

Answer (score 0):

Per the same documentation system classes are classes which do not have a class loader. Could be the classes found on the boot class path